# sharethis st_title and st_image are not loading

Tags: sharethis

I was using `Sharethis` in my website

but i am not getting the title and image

here is the code

```
<a ng-init="initShare()" class="st_sharethis_custom" st_title="{{profile.displayName}} Profile" st_image="{{profile.profileImage}}"></a>
```

and here is the output image

[image: image and title r not loading]

Comment: how is `{{profile.profileImage}}` resolved? using Angular?

Comment: does this code wont work???.... I am getting the value and starting it was coming properly but after some time it was not loading at all...